# How can I make a statement go through even though there's a needed break statement?

Tags: python, list, counter

My instructions are to help a child their way home. For example if the input is:

- R
  -JOHN
  -L
  -KING
  -L
  -SCHOOL
  this means that to get to school from his has he had to turn right on john, left on king, and left to school

The output needs to help him find his way back home an example of this is:

- R
- KING
  -R
  -JOHN
  -L
  -HOME
  This means that to get to his house from school he has to turn right on king, right on john, and left to home.

My problem is: I can't seem to try to incorporate all of the restrictions into the output. For the new directions home, I have to get rid of the first destination "school" and do opposite directions from the streets from there. So I tried that and it didn't work, but also, how can I figure out how to print out the directions with home? No directions print when HOME is printed...

```
directions = []
counter = 0
while True:
  direction = input("Enter L or R for the direction: ")
  street = input("Enter the street name: ")
  if street == "SCHOOL":
      break
  directions.append((direction, street))
  counter += 1
  if counter == 3:
      break

reversed_directions = []
for direction, street in directions:
    if direction == "L":
        direction = "R"
    elif direction == "R":
        direction = "L"
    reversed_directions.append((direction, street))

#It was working until I added in this bit
del reversed_directions[0]
reversed_directions.insert(2, "HOME")

print("Original directions:",directions)
print("New directions:",reversed_directions[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are checking if `street` is school way early before even appending it. This causes your loop to break and the data for `school` direction isn't updated.

Next, you don't need to reverse your list again in the end since it is already in the order you require. So remove `[::-1]`. Here's the fixed code:

```
directions = []
counter = 0
while True:
  direction = input("Enter L or R for the direction: ")
  street = input("Enter the street name: ")
  directions.append((direction, street))
  counter += 1
  if counter == 3 or street.casefold == "school":
      break

reversed_directions = []
for direction, street in directions:
    if direction == "L":
        direction = "R"
    elif direction == "R":
        direction = "L"
    reversed_directions.append((direction, street))

del reversed_directions[0]
if directions[0][0] == "L": # update Left or right based on first value
    reversed_directions.insert(2, ("R", "HOME"))
else:
    reversed_directions.insert(2, ("L", "HOME"))
# used f-strings for ease
print(f"Original directions: {directions}")
print(f"New directions: {reversed_directions}")
```

Input: `[("R", "JOHN"), ("L", "KING"), ("L", "SCHOOL")]`
Output:

```
>>> Original directions: [('R', 'JOHN'), ('L', 'KING'), ('L', 'SCHOOL')]
>>> New directions: [('R', 'KING'), ('R', 'SCHOOL'), ('L', 'HOME')]
```

Comment: the new directions give me the same output as the original...

Comment: Check it again? I provided your sample input and output